# IIS reverse proxy add Authorization header

Tags: iis, header, authorization, reverse-proxy, arr

I have set up Application Request Routing in IIS 8.5 for reverse proxy.
Proxy is working but I have to pass additional Authorization header to the site behind the proxy so it can authorize automatically. Problem is that it does not add the header. Is there something wrong with the configuration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://https://my.test.service.url.com/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" value="Bearer token12345=" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr

Comment: I suggest you could check you have added HTTP_AUTHORIZATION  Server Variables in the IIS url rewrite rule. You could open the the iis url rewrite rule on the left-hand pane, select "View Server Variables...". If you don't see HTTP_AUTHORIZATION listed, select "Add..." and add the server variable. Then you can go back and use it in your rule. and create rule to replace the value.

Comment: Can you please explain more ?

Comment: How i Can make the value dynamically?